# rename files keeping basename adding extra word and changing extension

Tags: bash

I have a script to encode video files. When I run this script, I would like to keep the basename of the file, add a 'modified' string to the filename and also changing the extension.

The following for loop does that with the exception of changing the extension:

```
for file in *.mkv;
do
  encode $file "${file%%.*}_modified.${i#*.}";
done
```

I'd like that `my_file.mkv` will become `my_file_modified.mp4`. The previous loop just converts `my_file.mkv` into `my_file_modified.mkv`

How to change also the extension from `.mkv` to `.mp4`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if I got your question right, and probably not; but if I did, you should just do this:

```sh
for file in *.mkv;
do
  encode $file "${file%.*}_modified.mp4";
done
```

The `${i#*.}` part in your previous command actually took the original extension from the file name; you can just omit it and set your own extension instead.

Also, as @M.NejatAydin pointed out in the comment, you should use `${file%.*}` instead of `${file%%.*}`, to keep the entire original filename if it has a dot inside it.

For example:

```sh
$ file="test.file.mkv"
$ echo "${file%%.*}_modified.mp4"
test_modified.mp4 # This is probably NOT what you want
$ echo "${file%.*}_modified.mp4"
test.file_modified.mp4 # This is probably what you want
```

Comment: Sometimes I'm just blind. Thx a lot!

Comment: I think the OP might have intended to use `${file%.*}` in place of `${file%%.*}`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thanks, I updated the answer!